# how to deal with stored properties's set and get in swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, properties, set

this is a way we deal with property in OC

```
- (void)setText:(NSString *)text
{
    if ([text isEqualToString:@"ss"]) {
        _text = @"xx";
        return
    }
    _text = text;
}

- (NSString *)text
{
    return _text;
}
```

this is a wrong way in swift, we can't call self.xx in set.

```
var text : NSString {
    get {
        return self.text
    }
    set {
        if newValue.isEqualToString("ss") {
            self.text = "xx"
        } else {
            self.text = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

My question is how to transfer the OC code to Swift code.

Comment: You can call `self` in get and set, as long as you're not calling `text`'s getter in `text`'s getter, or `text`'s setter in `text`'s setter. This is what you're currently doing, which is going to cause infinite loops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're confusing **stored** properties with **computed** properties.

Only computed properties have a getter and an optional setter; stored properties don't have either. Also, the setter in a computed property isn't there to set the value of the computed property (it can't, as the property is, well, computed and does not have an independent existence); rather, it's used to set the values of *other* properties, whose values are used to compute the computed property when it's next accessed. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29690521/set-value-to-computed-properties-in-swift/29691206#29691206) for an example of that.

Now, stored properties can have **property observers**. In your specific example, it would look like this:

```
var text : NSString! {
    didSet {
        if text.isEqualToString("ss" as NSString) {
            text = "xx" as NSString
        }
    }
}
```

You can also have a `willSet` block. Note that in Swift 1.2 NSString and String are no longer automatically bridged so you need to cast them onto each other when necessary.

Answer (score 1):

While I don't know much about using a getter and setter on a stored property, in your case you can just use a property observer `didSet`.

```
var text: String! {
    didSet {
        if text == "ss" {
            text = "xx"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way!

```
var text: NSString = ""

        var newText : NSString {
            get {
                return text
            }
            set {
                if newValue.isEqualToString("ss") {
                    text = "xx"
                } else {
                    text = newValue
                }
            }
        }
```