# How to use get and set in Swift

Tags: ios, get, swift2, set

I have a block of simple code calculating the area & perimeter of a rhombus.

```
 var perimeterOfRhombus: Double {
        get {
            let twoSides1 = sideLength1 + sideLength1
            let twoSides2 = sideLength2 + sideLength2
            let finalPerimeter = twoSides1 + twoSides2
            return finalPerimeter
        } set {
      }
    }
```

What I am missing is the set section.

I want it to show what sideLength1 and sideLength2 were in the beginning.

I am not sure what newValue is used for, when it has no value.

It does work without using set, but I see on Apple's `swift` language guide that set and get usually go together.

If set is really not needed in this code, what is it normally used for anyways?

Comment: Don't confuse your special example with general case. What would setting the area of a rhombus mean / do, is it logical? Unlikely. So your var should really be read only and have no setter

Comment: Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29690521/set-value-to-computed-properties-in-swift for a similar question.

Answer (score 18):

You should be referring to **Read-Only Computed Properties** instead of Computed Properties.

A computed property with a getter but no setter is known as a read-only computed property.It always returns a value, and cannot be set to a different value.

```
 var perimeterOfRhombus: Double {
  let twoSides1 = sideLength1 + sideLength1
  let twoSides2 = sideLength2 + sideLength2
  let finalPerimeter = twoSides1 + twoSides2
  return finalPerimeter
 }
```

Computed Properties do not actually store a value. Instead, they provide a getter and an optional setter to retrieve and set other properties and values indirectly.

Computed properties, including read-only properties must be set as a variable and not a constant.

```
 struct Square {
  var edge: Double = 0

  var area: Double {
    get {
      return edge * edge
    }
    set (newArea){
      edge = sqrt(newArea)
    }
  }
 }
```

In this case, setter can't be used to set the value of the property but to set the values of other properties, from which the computed property is computed.

About `newValue`, it's called **Shorthand Setter Declaration** - If a computed property’s setter does not define a name for the new value to be set, a default name of `newValue` is used.

So, the above example becomes

```
 struct Square {
  var edge: Double = 0

  var area: Double {
    get {
      return edge * edge
    }
    set {
      edge = sqrt(newValue) //someSquare.area = 25 (25 is newValue)
    }
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Computed property in swift using get and set

```
class Square {
    var side: Double = 0.0
    var area: Double {
        get {
            return side*side
        }
        set(newArea) {
            print(newArea)
            self.side = sqrt(newArea)
        }
    }
}

let obj = Square()
obj.side = 10.0
print(obj.area)
```